# Arduino: LiquidCrystal Won't Print With Ethernet Library

Tags: c++, arduino, microcontroller, ethernet, lcd

### Problem

I can't get my Arduino Uno's [LiquidCrystal](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/LiquidCrystal) library to print to my [LCD screen](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0059H60SK) when using the [Ethernet](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/Ethernet) library (and shield, of course).

### Code

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);
byte mac[] = {0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED};

EthernetClient client;

String text = "Original Text";

void setup() {
  // Set up the LCD's number of columns and rows: 
  lcd.begin(16, 2);

  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("Setup Text");

  // We have serial, but no milk!
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
  text = "Altered Text";
  if (Ethernet.begin(mac) != 0) {
      Serial.println("Some Ethernet work...");
  }

  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(text);
}
```

### Expected Result

*Let `▓` represent a blank character.*

The screen should print:
`Setup▓Text▓▓▓▓▓▓`
`Altered▓Text▓▓▓▓`

While `Some Ethernet work...` prints to Serial.

### Actual Result

The screen prints:
`Setup▓Text▓▓▓▓▓▓`
`▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓▓`

While `Some Ethernet work...` prints to Serial.

### Notes

If I comment out the Ethernet code in the loop, I get the **Expected Result**.

My question is similar -- but not identical to -- this question:
[Arduino code anomalies - LCD fails with multiple 'if' statements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14564714/arduino-code-anomalies-lcd-fails-with-multiple-if-statements)

I don't believe my problem is a shortage of memory.  I am using the most up-to-date Ethernet library, which fixes a [memory leak bug](https://code.google.com/p/arduino/issues/detail?id=933) from a previous version.

Comment: I may be onto something: http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29240/arduino-uno-ethernet-shield-16x2-lcd-not-initializing

Comment: I think this is kinda borderline ok for here....unless you really really think electronics.SE would be better. But I see you have an answer so feel free to mark as accepted.

Comment: @Kev I figured out the answer shortly after I asked the question.  But thanks for taking a look!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/29240/arduino-uno-ethernet-shield-16x2-lcd-not-initializing

`@ben as per the page here, the comment by user "njohnson" states that the shield uses all the digital pins except 1,2 and 8. based on this i tried hooking up the lcd to the 6 analog pins (as outputs) and its working fine now. Now the question is where/how can i study the shield schematic to be sure what all pins can i use. On a side now, it seems an unusual design decision since using the shield means sacrificing 13 of the digital pins ! – Ankit Apr 3 '12 at 21:14`

### Solution

I moved the LCD pins to analog pins (14-19).

### Code Modifications

Change `LiquidCrystal lcd(7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12);` to `LiquidCrystal lcd(19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14);` and move the LCD screen pins accordingly.